# Click and focus on input with CTRL

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a grid of inputs.
User is allowed to tab through them and click them.

When user is tabbing through inputs - next input is focused (event triggered by the browser). Focus event handler should add a "selected" class to an input.

When user clicks on an input - browser triggers "focus" event first and then "click" event.
Click event handler should add "selected" class to an input.

**Goal:**
I'm need to allow the user to select (add "selected" class to) multiple inputs with ctrl+click and still allow to tab through inputs.

**Problem:**
Focus event is fired before the click event and in consequence it removes the selection from all inputs.

Simplified version of the code: http://jsbin.com/emuboq/1/edit

Comment: If I understand correctly, what you're trying to achieve is not possible. You cannot have more than one element have the focus. However, as in your fiddle, you can "highlight" multiple elements, so this way a user selection of multiple elements can be preserved but only one of them will have the actual focus.

Comment: @MarcellFülöp Yes, obviously I want to highlight multiple inputs (add class) and not actually "focus" them :-)

Comment: Is this not what is already happening in your demo? While holding down the CTRL key and clicking different inputs, they get highlighted with blue border.

Comment: @MarcellFülöp it is, but "tabbing" doesn't work (see my comment in js code) and I need both to work.

Comment: I see.. How do you want it to work for tabbing? Like CTRL + tab should have the same effect as CTRL + click?

Comment: No, tabbing should work the same as clicking (without ctrl) - select a single input (unselect others).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my edits: http://jsbin.com/emuboq/7/edit

Not sure this is what you need, so let me know if not.